# Why does the second derivative method allow us to classify stationary points?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm learning how to find the nature of a stationary point using the second derivative method. I understood the first derivative method where you pick two close points near the target point and find whether the surrounding points are positive or negative, but I don't understand the second derivative method.

I usually benefit when I fully understand maths concepts instead of just memorizing them. I'm trying to visualize it.

> How does the rate of change of gradient in respect to x determine the nature of a stationary point on a quadratic curve at just a single point?

Comment: FYI - There are things called "capitalization" and "punctuation" that make writing much easier to read. When you are asking people for help, they are much more inclined to help you when you have not put all the work of interpreting your remarks on them, instead of doing what you can yourself to make your writing clear. That is why you have been voted down and ignored. (though not by me).

Answer (score 2):

Visualize an upside down parabola (or any convex curve), and consider the tangent line to the curve near its peak, starting at a point on the left, and then moving the point of tangency to the right. The tangent line is initially upward sloping, but as the point moves right its slope decreases to 0 as it reaches the peak. Then as it moves further right, the slope becomes negative as and decreases even more. That is, near the peak, the derivative of the function is itself a decreasing function.

Conversely, for a concave curve, on the left, the tangent line has negative slope, but that levels off as you move right, increasing to 0 at the minimum, then continues to increase, becoming more and more positive as moves to the right. I.e., the derivative of the function is itself an increasing function.

Finally, at an inflection point, the derivative similarly can be seen to change from either increasing to decreasing, or from decreasing to increasing, at the inflection, which means that the derivative has its own stationary point there.

Recall that a positive derivative means that a function is increasing and a negative derivative means that a function is decreasing. So, if the 2nd derivative is positive, that means that the derivative is increasing, an in particular if you are at a stationary point, it must be the one type of stationary point with an increasing derivative: a concave point. If the 2nd derivative is negative, then the derivative is decreasing, so the the stationary point must be the one type with a decreasing derivative: a convex point.

If the 2nd derivative is 0, then it could be any of the three, as the first two can also do their changes flat enough to have a 0 2nd derivative.